# Javascript's Function constructor - scope issues?

Tags: javascript

This code `new Function('fn', 'fn()')` creates anonymous function which has param and *(in this case the param is a function*)  executed.

Doing `console.log(new Function('fn', 'fn()'))` shows the output :

```
function anonymous(fn)
 {
  fn()
}
```

Now ,  the docs states :

> Note: `Functions` created with the `Function constructor` do **not** create
>   closures to their creation contexts; they always are *created in the
>   global scope*. When running them, they will only be able to access
>   their own `local variables and global ones`, **not** the ones from the scope
>   in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from
>   using eval with code for a function expression.

Ok.

So why does [this code](http://jsbin.com/darucivi/2/edit) yields `1`  and not `44` ?

```
var a = 44;

function myFunc()
{
    var a = 1;

    function f()
    {
        alert(a)
    }
    new Function('fn', 'fn()')(f);
}
myFunc();
```

Why ?

What about this line above ?

> they will only be able to access their own local variables and global
>   ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor
>   was called

It looks like the  `f` is closure over the parent `a` , but how  come ? it suppose to be run at global  , and able to access local and global only !

What am I missing ?

Comment: You passed `f` to the function and `f` is executed. **`f` has access to `myFunc`'s scope**...I don't think it would work if your code was `new Function("", "alert(a);")();` because `a` isn't accessible by the new function

Comment: @Ian Yes -  it wouldnt work had I wrote `alert` straight.  , but as I though , the param does create a closure.... they should have clear that in the docs that closured parameters IS accessible via the function

Comment: But what you just mentioned has nothing to do with the `new Function` constructor. Remember, you can pass a function around and execute it wherever - it has access to its own parent scope. `new Function` is no exception to this. Like I said, the docs are talking about the `new Function`'s scope, not any closures that are passed to that function. Because even in your example that you're questioning, as I pointed out with `alert(a)`, the new function doesn't have access to `myFunc`'s scope. You're not questioning the right scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're invoking function `f`, which is a normal function that does create a closure.

The documentation refers to this:

```
var a = 44;

function myFunc()
{
    var a = 1;

    new Function('fn', 'alert(a)')();  //shows 44, not 1
}
myFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you call *f* function that defined inside *myFunc* function. Does not matter where you called it from.  So you called you *anonymous* function that is defined in *global scope* and see *a = 44*, anonymous function called *f* function that is defined in *myFunc scope* and see *a = 1*.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve with this code, but if you need *44* in your *f* you need to pass it there as an argument.

```
var a = 44;

function myFunc() {
    var a = 1;

    function f(myArgument) {
        alert(myArgument)
    }
    new Function('fn', 'fn(a)')(f);
}
myFunc();
```